# Javascript pushing only last entry in for loop to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following code to populate a viewData object:

```
month = 1;
year = 2019;
days = 31;

// data object for return data
var viewData = {
 entries: []
};

// temp data stores
var jsonData = {};
var dict = {};

for (var i = 0; i < days; i++) {
  var dArr = [year, month, i+1];
  var storeDate = dArr.join("-");
  dict[storeDate] = 0;
}

for (var j in rows) { // I get rows from a SQL call, it works

    var fullString = formatDate(rows[j].EndTime); // this just uses a function to format a date
    var theDate = fullString.split(" "); // this get a date in the format YYYY-MM-dd
    dict[theDate] = dict[theDate] + rows[j].TotalDuration; // add the current duration to relevant dictionary entry
}

for (var p = 0; p < days; p++) {
  // create the date string for dictionary reference 
  var dArr = [year, month, p+1];
  var storeDate = dArr.join("-");

  // populate the jsonData object
  jsonData['timestamp'] = storeDate;
  jsonData['duration'] = dict[storeDate];
  // push the jsonData object to the viewData object
  console.log('---------------------------');
  console.log('Timestamp: ', jsonData['timestamp']);
  console.log('Duration: ', jsonData['duration']);
  viewData.entries.push(jsonData);
}
```

So from this code, when I print out the Timestamp and the duration in the for loop, I get the right values (E.g. "timestamp": "2019-01-04, "duration": 0). But, when I resolve and print out the viewData object, I get all entries with the timestamp value of "2019-01-31" and duration "0". These values are related only to the last iteration of the for loop.

Thus, it appears as if all entries in the viewData object are being populated only with the timestamp and duration values of the last iteration of the for look.

Why is this happening? Is there something related to how javascript works that I'm not understanding here?

Comment: Could you give us a mock for the `rows` variable? And maybe, use the code editor, so we'll get directly a result from your code. `formatDate` is also missing.

Comment: You're pushing `days` times the same object into `viewData.entries`. You have to push a new object instead.

Comment: Also `var` creates variables with function scope. So in your script there's only _one_ `dArr` and only _one_ `storeDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these two lines

```
 jsonData['timestamp'] = storeDate;
 jsonData['duration'] = dict[storeDate];
```

`jsonData['timestamp']` and `jsonData['duration']` are specific key-value pairs, and you're writing over them every time you iterate through. Then when you push it in the last line, it's only pushing a reference to the object, not the actual object. `console.log` doesn't happen quite as synchronously as you'd want, so sometimes by the time it's actually logging, it's only showing the updated object. You *could* do something like this:

```
jsonData[p] = {};
jsonData[p].timestamp = storeDate;
jsonData[p].duration = dict[storeDate];
```

Another option is making `jsonData` an array that you push a `{timestamp, duration}` object or `[timestamp, duration]` array into.

Also, you can turn these two lines

```
var dArr = [year, month, p+1];
var storeDate = dArr.join("-");
```

into a single line using a template string

```
var storeDate = `${year}-${month}-{p+1}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewData.entries.push(jsonData);` pushes a *reference* of the object "jsonData" to the array, not a copy. This means that when you alter the object jsonData, the reference that was pushed to the array will be changed as well.